# Android set degree symbol to Textview

Tags: java, android, textview, symbols

How can I set the degree symbol to a `TextView` in Android?

Comment: You can add/display ANY symbol using (char)<unicode> . For finding unicodes of various symbols goto http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x2200

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The unicode value for it is U+00B0 so you could do the following:

```
myTextView.setText ( "78" + (char) 0x00B0 );
```

Comment: It is not works, but if i do in the following
char tmp = 0x00B0;
myTextView.setText(tmp); will be okay!

Comment: Simpler would be to use Java's Unicode notation: `"78\u00B0"`, or `char degree = '\u00B0';`

Comment: Christopher Orr, you should post your comment as answer.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me.