# Need to send a string through Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

My code worked fine when I was just sending 1 letter or 1 number, but now I tried editing it to make it send two values and a ":" as well, but for some reason it doesn't work. Here is the code I am using:

```
@Override
  public void onMove(int angle, int strength) {
    mTextViewAngleLeft.setText(angle + "°");
    mTextViewStrengthLeft.setText(strength + "%");
    command = (angle + ":" + strength + "\n");
    try {
      outputStream.write(command.getBytes()); //transmits the value of command to the bluetooth module
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Command is declared as `String`.

Comment: try this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899475/android-sample-bluetooth-code-to-send-a-simple-string-via-bluetooth

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899728/3983054

Comment: 1) add some punctuation to your question. 2) `it doesn't work` how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: doesn't send anything at all to the arduino board

Comment: does it print any exception?

Comment: No nothing at all

Comment: then the problem might be on arduino side as well

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer i will check that as well

Answer (score 0):

This is a hunch, but the degree symbol may be causing the problem, try using the Unicode value.  [Help with Unicode Value here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439517/android-set-degree-symbol-to-textview)

Answer (score 0):

Turn out it was a hardware error (the Bluetooth was not working correctly)